# why is Navigation Component fragment Label not working

Tags: android, navigation

hello i am changing the label of fragment in navigation file but the fragment title in the tool bar isn't changing, any solution?

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="com.example.androidtask.view.UsersList"
        android:label="@string/user_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_users_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/submit_user"
            app:destination="@id/addUser" />

    </fragment>
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to setup ActionBar to work with navigation , add this code in activity `onCreate()`

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)// where nav_host_fragment is the id for your Main NavHost fragment
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

for more info check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

Comment: Can't do this with a BottomNavigateView.